# Selenium webdriver python - Bulk action in multiple tabs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, tabs

I did an automation project, on selenium webdriver chrome python
the code works very well but only in one time (i.e. in one tab)
The thing i want to do is do this action on several tabs (about 50 tabs open at the same time)
Here is the scenario I want to have:
1/ It opens the browser then connect
2/ it opens all 50 URLs (i.e. 50 tabs) in a single browser
3/ it goes back to tab number 1 to perform the action, when this is finished, it goes to tab number 2, and so on until it finishes all 50 tabs.

My codes are divided in 2, I ran them separately and it worked very well, yet I tried to merge them but it didn't work.

1st code: Add information then click on a publish button at the end of the action

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import os
import urllib3
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains



driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
driver.get("https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948987")


driver.find_element_by_id("identifierId").send_keys("*******@gmail.com")
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input').send_keys("************")
time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(3)



driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yDmH0d"]/c-wiz/div[2]/div[1]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div/span/div/div[9]/div/span/span/div').click()
time.sleep(3)

#titre posts
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c30"]').send_keys("Lorem ipsum")
time.sleep(2)

# supprimer le contenu dans le field
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c33"]').clear()
time.sleep(2)

# date debut
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c33"]').send_keys("1 déc. 2020")
time.sleep(2)

#ESC 1st JS Window
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c33"]').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
time.sleep(2)

# end date
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c40"]').send_keys("31 déc. 2020")
time.sleep(2)

#ESC 2nd JS Window
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="c40"]').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
time.sleep(2)

#expand extra field
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/button/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

#add description
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[7]/div/div/label/span[2]/textarea').send_keys("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,")
time.sleep(2)

#select CTA button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button/div').click()
time.sleep(2)

#select buy button
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[4]/span[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)

#add CTA URL
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[8]/div[3]/label/input').send_keys("https://www.example.fr")
time.sleep(2)

#upload photo
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

#step 2 upload photo
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":f"]/div').send_keys("/Users/*******/Documents/2020/Clients FR/*******.png")
time.sleep(2)



#clic publish
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[4]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)

#2nd code: a code that allows you to open several tabs at the same time.


from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.delete_all_cookies()
urls = ["https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948987",
        "https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948923",
        "https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948988",
        "https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948909",
        "https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948943",
        "https://business.google.com/posts/l/02451881054225948922"]
time.sleep(1)
for posts in range(len(urls)):
    #print(posts)
    driver.get(urls[posts])
    if(posts!=len(urls)-1):
        driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
        chwd = driver.window_handles
        driver.switch_to.window(chwd[-1])

#Can someone help me to make my code work?
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Selenium is considered to be not Thread-safe. So, I'm not sure what results you will get. In fact tell how this works for you. There will be an issue of the window/tab being in focus. Here's what you can try. Try it with say, 3-4 tabs and see what happens.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

from selenium import webdriver

def check_ip(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get(url)
    #Do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('urls.txt') as f: #Put the urls in a text with each url on a new line.No commas.
        urls = f.read().splitlines()

    with Pool() as pool:
        pool.map(check_ip, urls)
```

Comment: I tried 4 URLs and it opened 4 browsers simultaneously without opening the content of the URL.
it only displays "data:," in the URL bar
What alternative do you propose? thank you

Comment: Please check your txt file. No commas in between urls. One url on each line without any quotes and all include the "https//"..It must work.

Comment: it is already the case, no commas, one url on each line, no space, with https:// and without quotes.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshots, https://d.pr/free/i/iIoKDZ & https://d.pr/free/i/Y6xV8s

Comment: It works but your code opened one browser for each URL, so if I want to open 10 Urls at the same time it will open 10 browsers.
But what I want, the operation is performed in one browser with several tabs that are open.

Comment: I also tried to do this. When i used the code for opening new tabs it opens a new window, Let me look around and get back to you on this.

Comment: ` driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 'n')` This will open a new tab. However, the new tab covers the previous windows, I did this manually it seems that's the way it is in Chrome. What looks like a window is infact a tab. It says so on the top left.